# ignorecase in AWK

Tags: awk

The following command is working as expected.

```
# some command | awk '/(\<^create\>|\<^alter\>|\<^drop\>)/,/;/' 
create table todel1 (id int) max_rows=2
/*!*/;
alter table todel1 engine=InnoDB
/*!*/;
create database common
/*!*/;
create database rules
/*!*/;
```

But it matches only the lower case "create", "alter" etc. I want to use IGNORECASE switch in the awk statement so that it will return all instances of the search term.

Comment: The example in the accepted answer is mistakenly evaluating `IGNORECASE = 1` as a condition (with side effect), rather than as a statement in a block.  This condition is truthy, and will result in every line being printed *at least* once.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add `IGNORECASE = 1;` to the beginning of your awk command like so:

```
bash-3.2$ echo "Create" | awk '/^create/;'
bash-3.2$ echo "Create" | awk 'IGNORECASE = 1;/^create/;'
Create
```

Comment: Set it in the `BEGIN` block or on the command line since it doesn't need to be executed for each line of input.

Comment: Note that this is a `gawk`ism.  And to Dennis' second point, he means something along the lines of: `awk '/bunch of regex here/' IGNORECASE=1`

Comment: This does not work in awk version 20070501, at least. `echo "No match" | awk 'IGNORECASE = 1;/^create/;'` gives `No match`. It doesn't seem add the implicit if-statement if you have anything in addition to the regex.

Comment: As @ceykooo said this not working for me either.
But this is working for me:
`echo "No match" | awk 'tolower($0) ~ /^create/'`

Comment: This worked for me:  awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/search_item/' IGNORECASE=1 "${search_file}" > ./out.txt    (i was pulling out records between spaces in a file based on search string.

Comment: Set it in the BEGIN block or any block for that matter, or it doesn't work properly.  When it is not in a <code>{ }</code> block, all lines of text are matched in gawk 3.1.6 and 4.1.1 and probably universally.  I. E.  <code>echo -e "a\nb\nc" | awk 'IGNORECASE = 1; /B/' - </code> outputs four lines containing a, b, b, c!  <code>echo -e "a\nb\nc" | awk 'BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 } /B/' - </code> only outputs one line containing b.

Comment: FYI, this did not work properly for me when using `mawk`.  I installed `gawk` and all is now right with this world...

Comment: Thanks @DanielPérezRada. This is a far better solutions since it is defined in POSIX and thus not gawk specific. Also of course, it targets the specific comparison

Comment: Just to say, I marked this answer down.  The approximate reasons are given above, but specifically for me it was because it evaluates `IGNORECASE = 1` as a conditional expression when it should be in a block or set as a `gawk -v` variable.  As a condition, it will cause an implicit `{print $0}` to occur for every line.

Comment: echo -e "Create\na" | awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1;}/^create/;'

Comment: @mwfearnley you are correct!

Answer (score 22):

The following line executes an OR test instead of an AND :

```
echo -e "Create\nAny text" | awk 'IGNORECASE = 1;/^create/;'
Create
Create
Any text
```

The BEGIN special word (must be in uppercase) solved the problem :

```
echo -e "Create\nAny text" | awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1}/^create/;'
Create
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not so much an OR test, rather it just evaluates two expressions (one of which always evaluates to true), and so prints each input line either once or twice.

Comment: Note that "BEGIN" needs to be all upper case

Answer (score 12):

For those who have an *old `awk`* where the `IGNORECASE` flag is useless:

**Option 1**

```
echo "CreAte" | awk '/^[Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee]/'
```

**Option 2** (thanks @mwfearnley)

```
echo "CreAte" | awk 'tolower($0) ~ /^create/'
```

Comment: `those who have an old awk` ...like mac users :(

Comment: Late reply, i know but .. try to install the `GNU` version: http://brewformulas.org/Gawk @JoelMellon

Comment: Just to say, https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Case_002dsensitivity.html suggests using `tolower($0) ~ /.../` in non-GNU awks.

Comment: Thanks @mwfearnley I will try and feed the post back with the result

Answer (score 12):

This is a bit late, but [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5228938/446106) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34132156/446106) to this question (including the accepted answer) mention doing `awk 'IGNORECASE=1;...'` - i.e. putting `IGNORECASE=1` as a *condition*, instead of a statement in a block.

This should not be done.  It does set the variable as intended, but it also (as unintended) evaluates it as a boolean expression, returning true.

A true condition without a block will cause the line to always be printed.  If it happens to match the following pattern, it will also be printed a second time.

What the accepted answer probably meant was `awk '{IGNORECASE=1} ...'`, which sets the `IGNORECASE` variable on each line of text.  This can be further improved by using the `BEGIN` condition to assign it only once.  But a cleaner solution is to use the `-v` flag to set the parameter outside of the script logic:

```
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/(\<^create\>|\<^alter\>|\<^drop\>)/, /;/'
```

Note that `IGNORECASE` is specific to gawk.  For a non gawk-specific method, the [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Case_002dsensitivity.html) suggests using `tolower` in a pattern match:

```
awk '(tolower($0) ~ /(\<^create\>|\<^alter\>|\<^drop\>)/), /;/'
```