# Regex: ignore case sensitivity

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

How can I make the following regex ignore case sensitivity? It should match all the correct characters but ignore whether they are lower or uppercase.

```
G[a-b].*
```

Comment: Just have both the uppercase and lowercase included in the regex or convert to uppercase before doing the regex matching

Comment: G[a-bA-B].* would be the obvious in this general case, case sensitivity is afaik platform dependent and you're not giving a platform.

Comment: If you're using Java, you can specify this with the Pattern class: `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);`.

Comment: More Java options here:  https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/case_insensitive_matching_in_java

Comment: Note that for `grep`ing it is simply the addition of the `-i` modifier. Ex: `grep -rni regular_expression` to search for this 'regular_expression' 'r'ecursively, case 'i'nsensitive, showing line 'n'umbers in the result.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Correction:  `[Gg][abAB].*`  Your regex would have missed `gable` as it insisted on a capital `G`.

Comment: For JS/PHP/Python just add the flag `/i`, it works for me. Here is the [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/b11f1bfd1906).

Answer (score 706, accepted):

Assuming you want the **whole** regex to ignore case, you should look for the [`i` flag](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html). Nearly all regex engines support it:

```
/G[a-b].*/i

string.match("G[a-b].*", "i")
```

Check the documentation for your language/platform/tool to find how the matching modes are specified.

If you want only **part** of the regex to be case insensitive (as my original answer presumed), then you have two options:

1. Use the `(?i)` and [optionally] `(?-i)` mode modifiers:

   ```
   (?i)G[a-b](?-i).*
   ```
2. Put all the variations (i.e. lowercase and uppercase) in the regex - useful if mode modifiers are not supported:

   ```
   [gG][a-bA-B].*
   ```

One last note: if you're dealing with Unicode characters besides ASCII, check whether or not your regex engine properly supports them.

Comment: Brilliant! Works for: perl -pe 's/^utf-8\?B\?.*$//gi' Cancer.1631, matching/replacing string "UTF-8?B?" in file Cancer.1631. This fails: perl -pe 's/^utf-8\?B\?.*$//g' Cancer.1631, due to the case mismatch.

Comment: This post would much clearer if it wasn't such a specific example. Like what if you want to ignore case for another word such as ".txt" and ".TXT". From looking at this answer I'm still unsure how I could do this.

Comment: For some reason the regex that you posted doesn't work in `find` extended regex.. for example `find . \( -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex '/./[a-c][^.]*/i' \)` doesn't show any folders.. white a similar reged `find . \( -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex './[a-c][^.]*' \)` without the modifiers does show the correct folders. Any idea why?

Comment: Here I am trying to find all the folders starting with characters `[a-c]` in the current folder only.. to do some more manipulation..

Comment: Honestly I'd put option 2 in the main part of the answer as it is generic and works with all regex engines.

Comment: For Dart, the `RegExp` class has a parameter for it 
`RegExp(String source, {bool multiLine = false, bool caseSensitive = true,`

Comment: Thanks, this works. Here is the [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/b11f1bfd1906).

Answer (score 300):

Depends on implementation
but I would use

```
(?i)G[a-b].
```

**VARIATIONS:**

```
(?i) case-insensitive mode ON    
(?-i) case-insensitive mode OFF
```

Modern regex flavors allow you to apply modifiers to only part of the regular expression. If you insert the modifier (?im) in the middle of the regex then the modifier only applies to the part of the regex to the right of the modifier. With these flavors, you can turn off modes by preceding them with a minus sign (?-i).

Description is from the page:
https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

Comment: This is the modifier format for TortoiseHg's Search regex engine.

Comment: Could you tell me how this can be achieved in Linux shell (say in egrep without using the "-i" switch) generically?

Comment: Explaining what the `(?i)` does and how to end it (`(?-i)`) would have been really helpful. That's hands-down why your answer has 1/3 as many votes as the #1 question instead of almost as many, as they explain this subtle detail.

Comment: For who is using https://pypi.org/project/regex/, using (?i) in a regex which belongs to a regex composition (i.e. join of regex with ORs) will give to it an higher priority with respect the others (i.e. the order will be no more the same ad the regex are written)

Comment: Works for me in .NET/C#.

Comment: It is not about the language, but the regex engine implementation. But yes great to hear it is not something limited to perl :D.

Comment: In most regex flavors, you should add the modifiers at the end. Here is the [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/b11f1bfd1906).

Answer (score 105):

regular expression for validate 'abc' ignoring case sensitive

```
(?i)(abc)
```

Comment: Works perfectly with Android Studio logcat

Comment: Works in python too

Comment: Works in C# as well

Comment: Works in maXbox as well:
writeln(ReplaceRegExpr('(?i)\bsubstring\b',loadfile,'newstring',false));

Comment: Works fine in Java.

Comment: works in SparkSQL as well

Comment: @conner.xyz Soory it doesn't work in Python, here is the [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/38d882c967d6).

Answer (score 59):

The `i` flag is normally used for case insensitivity. You don't give a language here, but it'll probably be something like `/G[ab].*/i` or `/(?i)G[ab].*/`.

Comment: How can i make it works for `gàble`. check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/93c8ff645b75).

Answer (score 18):

Just for the sake of completeness I wanted to add the solution for regular expressions in C++ with Unicode:

```
std::tr1::wregex pattern(szPattern, std::tr1::regex_constants::icase);

if (std::tr1::regex_match(szString, pattern))
{
...
}
```

Comment: Can someone clarify to me why this post was downvoted? The accepted solution uses specific code and for the sake of completeness I wanted to add the solution for the standard libraries of the language c++. In my opinion I have generated added value to a more general question.

Comment: szPattern is OP's `G[a-b].*` whereas szString is the string to test

Answer (score 9):

In JavaScript you should pass the `i` flag to the `RegExp` constructor as stated in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags):

```
const regex = new RegExp('(abc)', 'i');

regex.test('ABc'); // true
```

Answer (score 8):

**JavaScript**

If you want to make it case insensitive just add `i` at the end of regex:

`'Test'.match(/[A-Z]/gi)` //Returns *["T", "e", "s", "t"]*

Without `i`

`'Test'.match(/[A-Z]/g)` //Returns *["T"]*

Comment: I checked the first regex, but it doesn't work for lattin character, here is the [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/77224c466d5f).

Answer (score 6):

C#

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...    
Regex.Match(
    input: "Check This String",
    pattern: "Regex Pattern",
    options: RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

specifically: **options: RegexOptions.IgnoreCase**

Answer (score 5):

As I discovered from this similar post ([ignorecase in AWK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228892/ignorecase-in-awk/)), on old versions of awk (such as on vanilla Mac OS X), you may need to use `'tolower($0) ~ /pattern/'`.

`IGNORECASE` or `(?i)` or `/pattern/i` will either generate an error or return true for every line.

Answer (score 3):

[gG][aAbB].* probably simples solution if the pattern is not too complicated or long.

Comment: would love to know why this answer is wrong for the given question?

Comment: You have it in your answer "is not too complicated or long"

Comment: This is actually the only solution that worked for my case. Also it looks like the most generic solution that should work everywhere. All other answers seem to be very specific for particular regex implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Addition to the already-accepted answers:

### Grep usage:

Note that for `grep`ing it is simply the addition of the `-i` modifier. Ex: `grep -rni regular_expression` to search for this 'regular_expression' 'r'ecursively, case 'i'nsensitive, showing line 'n'umbers in the result.

Also, here's a great tool for verifying regular expressions: https://regex101.com/

Ex: See the expression and Explanation in this image.

[image]

### References:

- man pages (`man grep`)
- http://droptips.com/using-grep-and-ignoring-case-case-insensitive-grep

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin:

```
"G[a-b].*".toRegex(RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `Regex` constructor has

```
Regex(String pattern, RegexOption option)
```

So to ignore cases, use

```
option = RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE
```

Answer (score -3):

You also can lead your initial string, which you are going to check for pattern matching, to lower case. And using in your pattern lower case symbols respectively .

Answer (score -4):

You can practice Regex In Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code using find/replace.

You need to select both Match Case and Regular Expressions for regex expressions with case. Else [A-Z] won't work.enter image description here

[image: Visual Studio 2019 Community]