# How do you write a makefile for both clang and gcc?

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I would like to use `std::experimental::filesystem` in my code, this requires me to compile using `-lstdc++fs` with GCC and `-lc++experimental` with Clang. At the moment I have a `makefile` and `makefile.clang` reflecting the difference in compilation, alternatively I've thought about using a clang build target so I can run `build clang`.

Is there some canonical way to set compiler-specific flags in a makefile?

Comment: Unrelated: You should be able to avoid this by upgrading to a compiler that supports C++17

Comment: Can you post makefiles you are currently using?

Comment: Assuming you use GNU Make (or some compatible `make` program) you can use [conditions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditionals) to set certain flags. Or you could use another build-system which generates the correct makefiles for you.

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri Here's a trimmed down version of the current makefile: https://pastebin.com/CvAvTdrd

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide helpful additional textual information (as text).

Comment: You can use cmake: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046114/in-cmake-how-can-i-test-if-the-compiler-is-clang

Comment: I know this is old, but this site is helpful for anyone looking for an answer: https://hiltmon.com/blog/2015/09/28/the-simple-c-plus-plus-makefile-executable-edition/ ... I have used this method for a long time without issue

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As the user "Some programmer dude" mentioned, there are [conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditionals) in GNU make. You could easily check for the compiler version this way:

```
CXXFLAGS = -Og -Wall -Wextra

GCC_CXXFLAGS = -DMESSAGE='"Compiled with GCC"'
CLANG_CXXFLAGS = -DMESSAGE='"Compiled with Clang"'
UNKNOWN_CXXFLAGS = -DMESSAGE='"Compiled with an unknown compiler"'

ifeq ($(CXX),g++)
  CXXFLAGS += $(GCC_CXXFLAGS)
else ifeq ($(CXX),clang)
  CXXFLAGS += $(CLANG_CXXFLAGS)
else
  CXXFLAGS += $(UNKNOWN_CXXFLAGS)
endif
```

Given the following source file `test.cpp` you can compile it with `make CXX=g++ test` or `make CXX=clang test` and it should pass the appropriate flags to each compiler.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World " << MESSAGE << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I will accept this as an answer because it's probably the closest thing you can get when only using make. It suffers from aliasing issues since for example MacOS have `g++` aliased to `clang` and versioned compilers like `g++-7` would presumably not work.

Answer (score 4):

In order to handle versioned compilers, like you mentioned in the comment to the accepted answer, you need to use `$(findstring find,in)` as such:

```
# Detect if CXX is g++ or clang++, in this order.
ifeq '' '$(findstring clang++,$(CXX))'
  LDLIBS = -lstdc++fs
else
  LDLIBS = -lc++experimental
endif
```

The caveat here is that you cannot use `$(findstring g++,$(CXX))` since it'll match `clang++` unintentionally.

A more in-depth alternative to handle things more precisely would be:

```
# Detect if CXX is clang++ or g++, in this order.
ifneq '' '$(findstring clang++,$(CXX))'
  LDLIBS = -lc++experimental
else ifneq '' '$(findstring g++,$(CXX))'
  LDLIBS = -lstdc++fs
endif
```

Answer (score 4):

This approach parses the compiler's version string looking for `clang`. If it doesn't find `clang` then it looks for `g++` in order to resolve an issue with macOS, where `g++` is aliased to `clang`.

```
# Set compiler-specific flags
GCC_CXXFLAGS = -DMESSAGE='"Compiled with GCC"'
CLANG_CXXFLAGS = -DMESSAGE='"Compiled with Clang"'
UNKNOWN_CXXFLAGS = -DMESSAGE='"Compiled with an unknown compiler"'

# Detect if CXX is clang++ or g++, in this order.
COMPILER_VERSION := $(shell $(CXX) --version)
ifneq '' '$(findstring clang,$(COMPILER_VERSION))'
  CFLAGS += $(CLANG_CXXFLAGS)
else ifneq '' '$(findstring g++,$(COMPILER_VERSION))'
  CFLAGS += $(GCC_CXXFLAGS)
else
  $(warning Unknown compiler)
  CFLAGS += $(UNKNOWN_CXXFLAGS)
endif
```

Credit to @bit2shift's answer, which inspired this one.