# How to check what compiler cmake is using?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm surprised I couldn't find this googling. I only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046114/in-cmake-how-can-i-test-if-the-compiler-is-clang), but I want to known how to find what compiler is cmake using in general? I also found [this](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-March/053819.html) but I assume there is some variable in cmake that just holds the compiler name, right?

Comment: `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` holds the name of the compiler. In general cmake uses [this script](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake) to find the compiler.

Comment: It depends of what do you want to do with the information (just print it, set compiler flags, etc). Can you please give an example of your CMake code in question (what have so far) and a concrete problem you want to solve?

Comment: I'm filling a bug report and it asks be for the compiler used to compile the code. So just printing the name is enough. This worked, if you could post it as an answer I could accept it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can see what variables are available in your CMake's binary output directory  `CMakeFiles/[your CMake's version]/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake`.

If you just want to print it, your are looking for [`CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_ID.html) and [`CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_VERSION.html). Those are available cross-platform.

Here are two examples of what CMake detects and generates from my projects:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID "GNU")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION "4.6.3")
```

Or

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID "MSVC")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION "19.0.24215.1")
```

Other kind of variables are there to check for platforms/toolchains like [`CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX.html).

Comment: I am using Android Studio. How do I find the CMakeFiles directory you mention?

Comment: Print Compiler Version: `message("Compiler Version: ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION}")`

Comment: @Ito You can find the directories and files under the .cxx generated folder

Comment: I just discovered that `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION` contains the compiler version in use when I did the first CMake call in the build folder. Since then system updates upgraded the compiler but `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION` still **contains the old version while in fact using the new version**! IMHO this makes the variable useless.

Answer (score 6):

I am not quite sure if I understood your question precisely, but if you just want to know which compiler is being used, enable a verbose build with the `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` option:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON
```

and then run `make` as usual. This will show which commands are used for building your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can check which compiler is being used by CMake by looking at the

> CMakeCache.txt

CMake generates a cache file (usually named CMakeCache.txt) in the build directory. This file stores various configuration settings, including the compiler being used. To check the compiler you can search for the term `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` or `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` it includes the path to the current compiler, you are configuring your project with.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in CMakeLists.txt to see the compiler cmake is using.

```
message (${CMAKE_C_COMPILER})
message (${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER})
message (${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_AR})
message (${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_RANLIB})
```

This works in cmake version 3.27.20230928-g92adbb5.