# Query Parse containsString make insensitive

Tags: ios, parse-platform, uisearchbar

I wonder if someone would be able to help. I am trying to search a Parse class for a term using `SearchBar`. The `containsString` however is case sensitive and i would like it to be case insensitive. Please see code below;

```
-(void)filterResults:(NSString *)searchTerm {

[self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: @"Firefacts"];
[query whereKeyExists:@"Number"];
[query whereKey:@"Number" containsString:searchTerm];
NSArray *results = [query findObjects];
[self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray:results];
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use Regular Expression `(?i)` instead ! credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9655203/2398886 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/9655186/2398886 and http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

So replace

```
[query whereKey:@"Number" containsString:searchTerm];
```

with

```
[query whereKey:@"Number" matchesRegex:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(?i)%@",searchTerm]];
```

or you can also use

```
[query whereKey:@"Number" matchesRegex:searchTerm modifiers:@"i"];
```

Your final code should be :

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: @"Firefacts"];
[query whereKeyExists:@"Number"];
[query whereKey:@"Number" matchesRegex:searchTerm modifiers:@"i"];
```

Comment: Great answer and works a treat, thank you so much for this :-)

Comment: Nice ! Works perfectly with swift too :D Good job !

Comment: I have been using this and it works. But what if I want to get an EXACT word match but also using a case insensitive regex?

Comment: @D34thSt4lker then surely you would just equalTo method instead?

Comment: @D34thSt4lker you can't have an EXACT insensitive match. The two contradict each other.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift use this:

```
query.whereKey("Number", matchesRegex: searchTerm, modifiers: "i")
```

reference: https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#queries