# Make search in text file case-insensitive

Tags: php, preg-match-all, case-insensitive, preg-quote

I'm using the following function to search for words in a text file. The problem is that this function is case-sensitive. I don't want it to be case-sensitive! How can I make the function case-insensitive?

```
$url = 'files/file.txt';
$thedata = file_get_contents($url);
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $thedata);

$search = 'some search words';
$pattern = preg_quote($search, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $thedata, $matches)) {
    echo implode('<br>', $matches[0]);    
} else {
    echo '<div class="message color-red">';
        echo 'Didn\'t find anything on that search!';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: `/^.*$pattern.*\$/im`?

Comment: There is `i` modifier

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex case sensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655164/regex-case-sensitive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `i` in addition to the `m` after the last `/` in your pattern string:

```
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/mi"
```