# Regular Exp match anything but not specific string

Tags: regex

I am handling user input in my program by using regular exp.

1. the string contains `/_MyWord/` and only a-z is accepted before `/_MyWord/`.
2. the string not contain `/s/123`, `/s/32A` and `atr/will` in the beginning.

My try:

```
^(?!.*/s/123)(?!.*/s/32A )(?!.*atr/will)([/a-z]+)/_MyWord/(.*)$
```

Example:

```
/s/123/QWERERTYU/_MyWord/45454545 -> fail
/DFGH/FGHJK/GHJK/_MyWord/DFGHJ452 -> OK
HiCanYouHelpMe/_MyWord/fgh        -> OK
/_MyWord/HiCanYouHelpMefgh        -> OK
```

Can anyone help me to finish the Regular Exp string

Comment: How can `/DFGH/FGHJK/GHJK/_MyWord/DFGHJ452` and `HiCanYouHelpMe/_MyWord/fgh` be OK if the substring before `/_MyWord/` can only contain lowercase letters and `/`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thx for your notice, I forgot the uppercase letters..

Comment: Then just use `/i` / `(?i)` case insensitive modifier.

Comment: It is a  dupe of [Regex case sensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655164/regex-case-sensitive).

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly, try this regex:

```
^(?!.*\/s\/123)(?!.*\/s\/32A)(?!.*atr\/will)([\/a-zA-Z]*)\/_MyWord\/(.*)$
```

Unescaped: `^(?!.*/s/123)(?!.*/s/32A)(?!.*atr/will)([/a-zA-Z]*)/_MyWord/(.*)$`

- Changed `([\/a-z]+)` to `([\/a-zA-Z]*)` to include lower and upper case as well as support none (e.g `/_MyWord/Test`)

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0PaeHb/1/)

Works for

```
/DFGH/FGHJK/GHJK/_MyWord/DFGHJ452
HiCanYouHelpMe/_MyWord/fgh
/_MyWord/HiCanYouHelpMefgh
```

Doesn't match:

```
/s/123/QWERERTYU/_MyWord/45454545
atr/will/DFGH/FGHJK/GHJK/_MyWord/DFGHJ452
```

Also, you really don't need lookaheads for `/s/123` and `/s/32A` since they contain numbers so they will automatically be rejected because your condition includes `[a-zA-Z]`. So you might want to remove `(?!.*\/s\/123)(?!.*\/s\/32A)` from the beginning.