# Multiple case insensitive strings replacement

Tags: java, java-8

I want to replace multiple case insensitive strings from a String.

I could have used:
 `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.replaceEach(text, searchList, replacementList)`

but is works for case sensitive strings.

Is there a similar method which works for case insensitive strings?

```
static String[] old = {"ABHISHEK","Name"};
static String[] nw = {"Abhi","nick name"};
static String s="My name is Abhishek";
System.out.println(StringUtils.replaceEach(s, old, nw));
```

Output:

```
My name is Abhishek
```

Expected:

```
My nick name is Abhi
```

Comment: "Is there a similar method which works for case insensitive strings?" Nope. You'll need to write one yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to archive it

Example

```
String str = "Dang DANG dAng dang";
//replace all dang(ignore case) with Abhiskek
String result = str.replaceAll("(?i)dang", "Abhiskek");
System.out.println("After replacement:" + "   " + result);
```

Result:

> After replacement:   Abhiskek Abhiskek Abhiskek Abhiskek

EDIT

---

```
String[] old = {"ABHISHEK","Name"};
String[] nw = {"Abhi","nick name"};
String s="My name is Abhishek";
//make sure old and nw have same size please
for(int i =0; i < old.length; i++) {
    s = s.replaceAll("(?i)"+old[i], nw[i]);
}
System.out.println(s);
```

Result:

> My nick name is Abhi

Basic ideal: [Regex ignore case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34219588/9218757) and [replaceAll()](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/string/java-string-replaceall-example/)

From the comment @flown (Thank you) you need to use

```
str.replaceAll("(?i)" + Pattern.quote(old[i]), nw[i]);
```

Because regex treats some special character with a different meaning, ex: `.` as `any single character`

So using the `Pattern.quote` will do this.

Comment: I want to replace multiple strings in one go. I'm passing String array.

Comment: @Ivar you can go with `str.replaceAll("(?i)" + Pattern.quote(old[i]), nw[i])`

Comment: @DangNguyen: Did you try running this program? It is giving me Output: My nick name is Abhishek

Comment: sorry my bad. yes it worked. Is there a batter way in java 8 using streams to achieve the same?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're already using `StringUtils`, [StringUtils.replaceIgnoreCase](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) is a good candidate to go with. Worth to mention that the version `3.5+` required.

> ```
> public static String replaceIgnoreCase(String text,
>                                        String searchString,
>                                        String replacement)
> ```
>
> Case insensitively replaces all occurrences of a String within another
>   String.
>
> A null reference passed to this method is a no-op.
>
> ```
>  StringUtils.replaceIgnoreCase(null, *, *)        = null
>  StringUtils.replaceIgnoreCase("", *, *)          = ""
>  StringUtils.replaceIgnoreCase("any", null, *)    = "any"
>  StringUtils.replaceIgnoreCase("any", *, null)    = "any"
>  StringUtils.replaceIgnoreCase("any", "", *)      = "any"
>  StringUtils.replaceIgnoreCase("aba", "a", null)  = "aba"
>  StringUtils.replaceIgnoreCase("abA", "A", "")    = "b"
>  StringUtils.replaceIgnoreCase("aba", "A", "z")   = "zbz"
> ```

In your case:

```
String[] old = {"ABHISHEK", "Name"};
String[] nw = {"Abhi", "nick name"};
String s = "My name is Abhishek";

for (int i = 0; i < old.length; i++) {
    s = StringUtils.replaceIgnoreCase(s, old[i], nw[i]);
}

System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
My nick name is Abhi
```

You can even create a helper method if you going to use it frequently:

```
public static String replaceIgnoreCase(final String s, final String searchList[], final String replacementList[]) {
    if (searchList.length != replacementList.length)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Search list and replacement list sizes do not match");

    String replaced = s;
    for (int i = 0; i < searchList.length; i++) {
        replaced = StringUtils.replaceIgnoreCase(s, searchList[i], replacementList[i]);
    }

    return replaced;
}
```

And use it like you would use a library call:

```
s = replaceIgnoreCase(s, old, nw);
```

Comment: The method replaceIgnoreCase(String, String, String) is undefined for the type StringUtils. I'm using commons-lang-2.6.jar

Answer (score 0):

in JAVA, Strings are case sensitive; if you want to use them insensitive you should use proper methods.
for example `equals()` is really different with `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

You can use:

```
 String.equalsIgnoreCase()
```

Or:

```
compareToIgnoreCase()
```

and if these methods return a proper data you can use them to replace them with String which you want.