# ignore case regex

Tags: java, regex

How do I ignore case for my match? I am trying to match:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)^concat\\(",Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("CONCAT(trade,ca)");
    System.out.println(matcher.find());
}
```

Possible scenarios

```
CONCAT( = true
concat( = true
CONCAT(test = true
concat(test = true
concat = false
CONCAT = false
TESTCONCAT( = false
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex: ignore case sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655164/regex-ignore-case-sensitivity)

Comment: `concat != COCNAT` ...

Comment: oops ! that typo otherwise i guess my regex is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pattern` has the flag `CASE_INSENSITIVE` so all you need is

```java
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^concat\\(",Pattern.MULTILINE+Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: The literal flag OP uses is fine too. But I agree flags in the factory method might make the pattern itself a little more readable.