# Regular Expression for string with any type of case variation

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a solution for a regex pattern, that is needed to determine if a word is matching the pattern, but for any variation of it.

For example: The pattern needs to match: "phone", but it also needs to match: "Phone", "PHONE", "pHone", "phOne", etc. So it shouldn't matter the type of case for any position in that string.

Is that possible in regex? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Set the `i` flag for case **i**nsensitive.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655164/regex-ignore-case-sensitivity for examples.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for my regex engine, I wish it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain regex, you can do:

```
[Pp][Hh][Oo][Nn][Ee]
```

If you are using a programming language, it might be simpler to test if `string.lower() == "phone"`.

Comment: Thank you! I think that's what I need!