# How to handle mixed cases regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of keywords to search for. Most of them are case insensitive, but a few of them are case sensitive such as IT or I.T. for information technology. Usually, I join all the keywords together with "|", and set the flag to re.I. This will cause trouble for the case-sensitive keywords. Is there an easy way to get around this? Or I have to run a separate search for the case-sensitive ones? Thank you!

```
 keywords = ["internal control", "IT",... and many more]
 patterns = r"\b(" + "|".join(keywords) + r")\b"
 m = re.findall(patterns, text, flags = re.I)
```

Comment: among the _many more_ `keywords`, how can you tell which ones are case-sensitive and which ones aren't?  Would all-caps mean the word is case-sensitive?

Comment: The abbreviations are case-sensitive(all-cap). The rest are case insensitive.

Comment: I think you would need two separate searches, which you could implement from the same keywords list by checking whether a particular keyword is all upper-case or not.  Is regex the only option for you or have you thought about some other substring search options?

Comment: I will go with two separate searches then. regex seems to be more efficient, dealing with a few hundred keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(?-i:...)` modifier to turn off case-insensitive search for this group. But it works only on Python 3.6+:

```
import re

s = "Internal control, it IT it's, Keyword2"
keywords = ["internal control", "IT", "keyword2"]
pattern = '|'.join(r'((?-i:\b{}\b))'.format(re.escape(k)) if k.upper() == k else r'(\b{}\b)'.format(re.escape(k)) for k in keywords)
print(re.findall(pattern, s, flags=re.I))
```

Prints:

```
[('Internal control', '', ''), ('', 'IT', ''), ('', '', 'Keyword2')]
```

From Python 3.6 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html):

> (?imsx-imsx:...)
>
> (Zero or more letters from the set 'i', 'm', 's', 'x', optionally followed by '-' followed by one or more letters from the same set.)
>   The letters set or removes the corresponding flags: re.I (ignore
>   case), re.M (multi-line), re.S (dot matches all), and re.X (verbose),
>   for the part of the expression. (The flags are described in Module
>   Contents.)

Comment: This is great! Thank you!

Comment: One thing I noticed that is that surrounding the entire regex with \b runs faster. ie. \b(?:(kw1)|(kw2)|...))\b

Answer (score 1):

*(Posting this as an answer because it is too much text for a comment)*
I still think two separate searches would be cleaner and simpler.  So this may be academic: you could possibly use some combination of [Conditional regex](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html) and [optional mode modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655164/regex-ignore-case-sensitivity) as indicated in the respective links.

Comment: Thank you! This is a good option. Conditional regex and optional mode modifiers are very useful.