# Why does tidyr extract not respect the ignore_case flag?

Tags: r, regex, extract, tidyverse, tidyr

I would excpect that I can pass a `regex` to tidyr's `extract` and set the `ignore_case` to true. But it does not work apparently:

```r
tidyr::extract(
  tibble("Value"),
  col = 1,
  into = c("result"),
  regex = regex("(value)", ignore_case = TRUE)
)
```

This should result in a tibble with one column `result` and one row with value `Value`. But it does not, the cell is `NA`.

With a capital letter, the same code works:

```r
tidyr::extract(
  tibble("Value"),
  col = 1,
  into = c("result"),
  regex = regex("(Value)", ignore_case = TRUE)
)
```

Passing `ignore_case = TRUE` or `ignore.case = TRUE` directly as an argument to `extract` does not solve the problem.

Comment: No idea what's going on, but `regex = regex("(?i)(value)")` works.

Comment: The `regex` function is from a different package, **stringr**. I haven't dug into the code much, but it's likely that tidyr functions simply weren't written to use that special function from another package.

Comment: [Here is a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9655203/3832970).

Comment: You can check the github issue related to this post https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/223

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thx wiktor, that works indeed:

```r
tidyr::extract(
  tibble("Value"),
  col = 1,
  into = c("result"),
  regex = "(?i)(value)"
)
```