# Blacklist, case-insensitive regex for client-side validation

Tags: regex

I'd like to implement some client-side validation for a case-insensitive, blacklisting of variations on a word. For example, if the word in question is `Dog`, a user should not be able to enter any variation of it:

```
dog
doG
dOg
dOG
Dog
DoG
DOg
DOG
```

Was trying to experiment with a negative lookahead, i.e., `^(?!.*(?:dog|doG|dOg|dOG|Dog|DoG|DOg|DOG))` but that seems too verbose and not generic enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex: ignore case sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655164/regex-ignore-case-sensitivity)

Comment: Convert user entered value to lowercase and then compare with `dog`

Comment: @Tanner, would I still need to include all variations of said word, hardcoded into the expression?

Comment: Nope, your regex should be /dog/i <- where i is the case-insensitive flag. that will cover doG, DOG, Dog, DoG and so on