# How to optimize lowercase and capitalize formats extensions?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have this code and works correctly but I'm wondering if it can be optimized to not repeat the formats in capitalize & lowercase `(?:mp4|MP4|webm|WEBM|mov|MOV|ogg|OGG))`

```
$post[message] = preg_replace('/<a href="(.+?\.(?:mp4|MP4|webm|WEBM|mov|MOV|ogg|OGG))" target="_blank">(.+?)<\/a>/', '<video controls="" src="$1" style="max-width: 640px; max-height: 360px;outline:none;" loop>VIDEO HTML5</video>', $post[message]);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex: ignore case sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655164/regex-ignore-case-sensitivity)

Comment: In place of `.+?`, better to use `[^"]+`.

Comment: Thank you for the sugestion, I would like to know why is better?

Comment: 1. you are sure that it doesn't match outside of the attribute value. 2. a greedy quantifier is faster since it reaches quickly the end of the attribute and backtracks only 4 times to be able to check the extension subpattern. (a lazy quantifier has to check this subpattern from the start of the attribute for each character until the end (-4 characters)).

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip and explanation :)