# MongoDB: Match multiple values in string field

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of entities that contain a string field. I'm looking for a way to query the collection with a combined number of values, and get all entities that contain all of these values, with these specifications:

1. contain ALL provided query values, not just some of them
2. case-insensitive
3. regardless of order
4. 'word' query values can be part of something bigger (for example separated by _ or any other character)

So as an example, if I provide these words as the query values:
`i am spiderman`
(I can separate them by whitespace, give an array, or whatever works..)

I expect these results:

```
 - "i am_spiderMan"                     // should match
 - "AM i spiderman?!"                   // should match
 - "who am I? supermanspiderman"        // should match
 - "I am superman"                      // should not match
 - "i am spider_man"                    // should not match
```

I hope this covers all the cases I tried to describe.
I tried regex, and also did some research with similar questions but could not get it to work.

Comment: It looks like you are looking to create a regex, but do not know where to get started. Please check [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) resource, it has plenty of hints. Also, refer to [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736) post for some basic regex info. Once you get some expression ready and still have issues with the solution, please edit the question with the latest details and we'll be glad to help you fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use regular expr. This is working perfectly. When you pass the sentence, you need to put all worlds into array as I have shown below. Refer [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) to include all words to find. [Reg expr case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655164/regex-ignore-case-sensitivity)

```
db.collection.find ({ key: { $all: [ /spiderman/i, /i/i, /am/i ] } })
```