# Case insensitive comparison of strings in .gitlab-ci.yml file of GitLab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have some variable with name 'MyVariable' and want to compare it with some string constant inside rules: if section inside job:

```
rules:
        - if: $MyVariable == 'some string'
```

But MyVariable actually can be in different cases, like:

```
SOME STRING
Some String
SoME strinG
```

and so on.
Current comparison (==) is case-sensitive, and expression results to 'false' when MyVariable is not exactly 'some string' (in lower case). Is there any possibility compare two strings in case-insensitive way?

Comment: Using `=~` lets you use a regular expression. You can use case-insensitive expression -- `- if: '$MyVariable =~ /(?i)some string/'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `=~` instead of `==` lets you use a [regular expression](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#regular-expressions). You can use case-insensitive expression or add the case-insensitive flag `i`:

> Regular expression flags must be appended after the closing /. Pattern matching is case-sensitive by default. Use the i flag modifier, like `/pattern/i` to make a pattern case-insensitive:

```yaml
- if: '$MyVariable =~ /some string/i'
```

Additional references:

[Regex: ignore case sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655164/regex-ignore-case-sensitivity)