# .htaccess - How to use SetEnvIf with case insensitive parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am using this code to set the varialbe **MAGE_RUN_CODE**.
How can I make Android|Opera case insensitive in `SetEnvIf User-Agent Android|Opera MAGE_RUN_CODE=app`?

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE store
SetEnvIf Host ^company.de MAGE_RUN_CODE=default
SetEnvIf Host ^app.company.de MAGE_RUN_CODE=app
SetEnvIf User-Agent Android|Opera MAGE_RUN_CODE=app
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SetEnvIfNoCase` directive instead to enable a case-insensitive match. For example:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent android|opera MAGE_RUN_CODE=app
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvifnocase

---

Alternatively, you can use the `(?i)` mode modifier on the regex itself. For example:

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent (?i)android|opera MAGE_RUN_CODE=app
```

Reference:

- [Regex: ignore case sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655164/regex-ignore-case-sensitivity)