# MongoDB how to search by using regex but avoiding case sensitive?

Tags: mongodb, go

Here is what I have done so far

```
filter := bson.M{
    "$or": bson.A{
        bson.M{"title": bson.M{"$regex": "input"}},
        bson.M{"author": bson.M{"$regex": "input"}},
        bson.M{"content": bson.M{"$regex": "input"}},
    },
}

p.postProposalCollection.Find(ctx, filter)
```

but it is case sensitive, is there anyway to lowercase the column `title`, `author`, `content` then try to search with regex.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655164/regex-ignore-case-sensitivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do the case-insensitive regex search, you can use the Regex primitive with "i" flag:

```
bson.M{"title": bson.M{"$regex": primitive.Regex{Pattern: "input", Options: "i"}}},
```

See [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#mongodb-query-op.-regex) and [here](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive#Regex) for details.