# Python Regex to Capture Proceeding Text - mixing cas insensitivity in group

Tags: python, regex, case-insensitive

[Example Link](https://regex101.com/r/idaN2R/1)

RegEx Group returning issue:

```
(?P<qa_type>(Q|A|Mr[\.|:]? [a-z]+|Mrs[\.|:]? [a-z]+|Ms[\.|:]? [a-z]+|Miss[\.|:]? [a-z]+|Dr[\.|:]? [a-z]+))?([\.|:|\s]+)?
```

Objective:
To extract text from proceeding transcript pdfs for each question/answer/speaker type.

Using Python: interage through pages in PDF extracted text and group Qestion/Answer text.

Desired Results = qa_type, page_start, page_end, line_num_start, line_num_end, qa_text

ISSUE:
For the [Q|A] designators, I only want upper case, but for the speaker Titles (Mr, Mrs., Dr., etc.) case insensitive is required, both Q|A and spearker salutation a single 'qa_type' group.

Request: How do I prevent 'qa_type' from captureing 'a' or 'q'?  See lines 2 and 17 on pp 275.

[Example bad extract - line 17 'a'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36a2g.png)

```
regex = r"(^(?P<line_num>[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-2])\b +)(?P<qa_type>(Q|A|Mr[\.|:]? [a-z]+|Mrs[\.|:]? [a-z]+|Ms[\.|:]? [a-z]+|Miss[\.|:]? [a-z]+|Dr[\.|:]? [a-z]+))?([\.|:|\s]+)?(?P<type_text>\b.*)|page (?P<page_num>\d{1,3})"
```

Comment: That final RegEx seems very complicated. Big RegExs are hard to maintain when changes are needed. I suggest using several simpler RegExs. The character classes seem strange; note that `[.|:|\s]` is the same as `[|.:\s]`. There are several  uses of `[.|:]`, are the three characters allowed, or is the `|` intended to mean `.` or `:`? A `|` means itself within a character class (i.e. between square brackets).

Comment: @AdrianHHH, thank you for the feedback as this is very helpful.  I will refactor this once I get things working.  Please recommend any other ideas for a more manageable approach, as I will be using this on millions of PDFs, so there will be variations in parsing syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds pretty similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655164/regex-ignore-case-sensitivity). Unfortunately, it seems like python inline flag modifiers have been deprecated. You can still try to use them, in which case your regex would look like this (without the global case-insensitive flag):

```
(^(?P<line_num>[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-2])\b +)(?P<qa_type>(Q|A|(?i)Mr[.|:]? [a-z]+|Mrs[.|:]? [a-z]+|Ms[.|:]? [a-z]+|Miss[.|:]? [a-z]+|Dr[.|:]? [a-z]+(?-i)))?([.|:|\s]+)?(?P<type_text>\b.*)|(?i)page(?-i) (?P<page_num>\d{1,3})
```

The alternative is to just specify both the lowercase and uppercase characters every time you want a case-insensitive letter (again, without the global case-insensitive flag):

```
(^(?P<line_num>[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-2])\b +)(?P<qa_type>(Q|A|[mM][rR][.|:]? [a-zA-Z]+|[mM][rR][sS][.|:]? [a-zA-Z]+|[mM][sS][.|:]? [a-zA-Z]+|[mM][iI][sS][sS][.|:]? [a-zA-Z]+|[dD][rR][.|:]? [a-zA-Z]+))?([.|:|\s]+)?(?P<type_text>\b.*)|[pP][aA][gG][eE] (?P<page_num>\d{1,3})
```

[Updated regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/SxlBHI/1)

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me.  I saw the answer you referenced, but I did not extract the example you provided in the alternative above.  It appears that Python 3.11 has removed the inline case-insensitive flag.  I look to refactor this to a simpler, more pythonic approach after I get things working.